# Why would /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/token be an empty file in a Pod?

Tags: kubernetes, minikube

I'm using a vanilla minikube environment.

I'm not specifying any service account-related instructions in my bare-bones simple Pod `.yaml` file.

Inside a deployed Pod, `/var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/token` is empty.  What are the possible causes for this?

Comment: which minikube/k8s versions are you using?

Comment: minikube 0.24.1.

Answer (score 7):

As mentioned [in the docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-service-account/#use-the-default-service-account-to-access-the-api-server)

> In version 1.6+, you can opt out of automounting API credentials for a service account by setting automountServiceAccountToken: false on the service account:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ServiceAccount
metadata:
  name: build-robot
automountServiceAccountToken: false
```

> In version 1.6+, you can also opt out of automounting API credentials for a particular pod:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: my-pod
spec:
  serviceAccountName: build-robot
  automountServiceAccountToken: false
```

So double check your pod file and check your ServiceAccount configuration with
`kubectl describe serviceaccount build-robot` to see if you are disabling the automount.

Comment: Thanks very much for your answer; it's a really good thought, and I learned something from it.  Unfortunately, that's not what's going on.  :-(

Comment: Does the ServiceAccount exist?

Comment: `ls -al` shows the `token` symlink pointing at the `..data` symlink pointing at the real file, as it should.  Any attempt to `cat` it yields nothing.

Answer (score 0):

I was having this issue with minikube v1.13.1 on Ubuntu 18.04, using the 'none' driver to run Kubernetes v1.19.2 on Docker 19.03.6.

I was seeing that the serviceaccount token secret was correctly populated in Kubernetes, and that it was mounted as a volume for each pod, but that the directory (both in the pod and on the node itself) was empty.

I found the problem was caused by disabling the 'storage-provisioner' addon, and resolved by re-enabling it.