# Kubernetes pod secrets /var/run/secrets missing

Tags: kubernetes, terraform, minikube, traefik

#### TL;DR:

Kubernetes pods created via terraform don't have a `/var/run/secrets` folder, but a pod created according to the `hello-minikube` tutorial does - *why is that, and how can I fix it*?

Motivation: I need traefik to be able to talk to the k8s cluster.

#### Details

I have set up a local Kubernetes cluster w/ minikube and set up terraform to work with that cluster.

To set up traefik, you need to create an `Ingress` and a `Deployment` which are [not yet supported by terraform](https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-kubernetes/issues/3). Based on the workaround posted in that issue, I use an even simpler module to execute yaml files via terraform:

```
# A tf-module that can create Kubernetes resources from YAML file descriptions.
variable "name" {}
variable "file_name" { }
resource "null_resource" "kubernetes_resource" {
  triggers {
    configuration = "${var.file_name}"
  }
  provisioner "local-exec" {
    command = "kubectl apply -f ${var.file_name}"
  }
}
```

The resources created in this way show up correctly in the k8s dashboard.

However, the ingress controller's pod logs:

```
time="2017-12-30T13:49:10Z" 
level=error 
msg="Error starting provider *kubernetes.Provider: failed to create in-cluster
    configuration: open /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/token:
    no such file or directory"
```

*(line breaks added for readability)*

`/bin/bash`ing into the pods, I realize **none of them** have a path `/var/run/secrets`, except for the `hello-minikube` pod from the [minikube tutorial](https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube), which was created with just two `kubectl` commands:

```
$ kubectl run hello-minikube --image=k8s.gcr.io/echoserver:1.4 --port=8080
$ kubectl expose deployment hello-minikube --type=NodePort
```

Compared to the script in the terraform issue, I removed `kubectl` params like `--certificate-authority=${var.cluster_ca_certificate}`, but then again, I didn't provide this when setting up `hello-minikube` either, and the original script doesn't work as-is, since I couldn't figure out how to access the provider details from `~/.kube/config` in terraform.

I tried to find out if `hello-minikube` is doing something fancy, but I couldn't find its source code.

Do I have to do something specific to make the token available? According to [traefic issue 611](https://github.com/containous/traefik/issues/611), the InCluster-configuration should be automated, but as it currently stands I'm stuck.

#### Versions

Host system is a Windows 10 machine

```
> minikube version
minikube version: v0.24.1

> kubectl version
Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"9", GitVersion:"v1.9.0", GitCommit:"925c127ec6b946659ad0fd596fa959be43f0cc05", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2017-12-15T21:07:38Z", GoVersion:"go1.9.2", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"windows/amd64"}
Server Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"8", GitVersion:"v1.8.0", GitCommit:"0b9efaeb34a2fc51ff8e4d34ad9bc6375459c4a4", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2017-11-29T22:43:34Z", GoVersion:"go1.9.1", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
```

#### Related

There are some related questions and github issues, but they didn't help me fix the problem yet either.

- [How do I access the Kubernetes api from within a pod container?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30690186/how-do-i-access-the-kubernetes-api-from-within-a-pod-container)
- [Why would /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/token be an empty file in a Pod?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47721646/why-would-var-run-secrets-kubernetes-io-serviceaccount-token-be-an-empty-file-i)
- https://github.com/datawire/telepresence/issues/353
- https://github.com/openshift/origin/issues/13865

Comment: Foremost, thank you for an **amazing** question write up; I would use this question as a template for how others should ask! Can you check the `automountServiceAccountToken` field in the `PodSpec` and see if it is `true`? The only other constructive question I know is whether its `serviceAccountName` points to an existing S.A.; I would hope a bogus one would bomb the deploy, but don't know for sure what will happen in that case

Comment: Thank you so much!! Setting `automountServiceAccountToken` immediately fixed the problem. I was staring right at it but I just didn't see what was going on ;) Care to post this as an answer?
The fact that it just deployed without even complaining certainly made this harder to pinpoint, but I guess that's a problem of the traefik image?

Comment: *I guess that's a problem of the traefik image* unknown, but it certainly seems reasonable to check their issue tracker and see if we can't improve the experience for the next person, as that's 100% something the image _could_ guard against

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Foremost, thank you for an **amazing** question write up; I would use this question as a template for how others should ask!

Can you check the `automountServiceAccountToken` field in the `PodSpec` and see if it is `true`?

The only other constructive question I know is whether its `serviceAccountName` points to an existing S.A.; I would hope a bogus one would bomb the deploy, but don't know for sure what will happen in that case

Comment: It would probably be better if you converted this comment-like answer to a real answer by cutting out some of the chattiness/questioning parts and focusing on what actually fixed the issue here. It looks like the middle paragraph but without any K8s knowledge I don't know where the `automountServiceAccountToken` is set in the Terraform resource (or if it's that all). Tidying this up would help people who also run into this issue in the future.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion caused by this behaviour. Just to add some context here: https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-kubernetes/issues/56